# How to style the first occurance of a class anywhere in a page/element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I add the style `text-decoration:line-through` to the first `span class="price"` element in my table ?

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="25%">
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="first odd">
          <th class="label">Style Number</th>
          <td class="data last">2403</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
          <th class="label">Style Name</th>
          <td class="data last">Easy Option Berber</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
          <th class="label">Rating</th>
          <td class="data last">3.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
          <th class="label">Retail Price</th>
          <td class="data last"><span class="price">$2.23</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
          <th class="label">Price</th>
          <td class="data last"><span class="price">$1.44</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
          <th class="label">Roll Price Begins At</th>
          <td class="data last">125</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
          <th class="label">Face Weight</th>
          <td class="data last">50</td>
      </tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: I have reviewed the answers here, but they do not apply as my class is not in the same parent element:
[CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Example (doesn't work):

```
#product-attribute-specs-table tbody > tr td.data .price {text-decoration:line-through}
#product-attribute-specs-table tbody > tr td.data .price ~ tr td.data .price {text-decoration:none}
```

---

I should, also, note that `class="price"` is used several times in the page. I just need to target the first one inside the table.

Comment: I don't think `css` can do that in this context

Comment: any luck trying `span:first-of-type` ?

Comment: `span:first-of-type` styles both "price" elements as they are both the first in their parent container.

Comment: how about using JS? or as a workaround placing them under different `div` or giving a different class name?

Comment: I was able to modify the HTML output to wrap the first one in another container that I could style separately. However, I was hoping I could just add 2 lines of CSS and be done... :/ JS would have worked, but would have added more weight to the site than I wanted. But, if that's the only option, then that's the only option.

Comment: Your example is right, your selector is just nesting too deep. The sibling selector is based on the last nesting level it arrived at. So you need to make it more general. `#product-attribute-specs-table tbody > tr td.data .price {text-decoration:line-through}
#product-attribute-specs-table tbody > tr ~ tr td.data .price {text-decoration:none}`

Comment: @yaycmyk I tried your suggestion, but both lines select both elements: https://jsfiddle.net/hn89cp55/

Comment: @MichaelYaeger Why you can't add additional class with first `span.price`? I think it will be easiest way to fix it.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman, I did just that. However, editing the source code took twice as long as I was hoping would happen with just a small CSS update. We'll have to push scenarios like this into #CSS4! :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need JS for this:

```
document.getElementById('product-attribute-specs-table')
  .querySelector('span.price')
  .classList.add('line-through');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        .chartKeyListItem {
            margin-left: 60px !important;
                }

              .chartKeyListItem ~ .chartKeyListItem {
               margin-left: 0 !important;
                  }
```

if you are using Dom elements use this

```
       event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
```

Using the classList property of DOM elements which return a DOMTokenList Object of classes(already split by space)

```
       event.target.classList[0];
```

Comment: `class="price"` is used several times in the page. I just need to target the first one inside the table.